# Delete Last line from txt file by using Batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to remove my last blank line of .txt file by using batch script.
My last line will be always blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using *sed*:

```
sed '$d' in
```

*$* indicates the last line and *d* means to delete the matched pattern.

Comment: is the code will be sed'$d' in (sqloutfile.txt) do >>newfile.txt echo %i

Comment: sed '$d' sqloutfile.txt > newfile.txt

Comment: That is in bash is it not?, this is in reference to batch.

Answer (score 0):

If your output file has only one blank line and by a blank line you mean an empty line - containing no characters then as a batch-file command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (sqloutfile.txt) do >>newfile.txt echo %%i
```

Or from the prompt,

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (sqloutfile.txt) do >>newfile.txt echo %i
```

Comment: Hi Still the blank line exists at the end of the line.

Comment: @dadde : Assuming that `newfile.txt` does not already exist, the posted code will fille `newfile.txt` from `sqloutfile.txt`, excepting any empty lines, wherever they appear in `sqloutfile.txt`. By an empty line, I mean any line which contains no characters whatever. If your experience is different, please show me a file complying with OP's specifications where it fails. Please observe that OP wanted to delete the last line in the file and stated it was "blank". Regrettably,OP did not clarify whether he meant that last line was empty or whether it contained one or more spaces.

Comment: @Magoo Well I tried it and it did not really work. Also an empty line is never empty, it always contains line feed and/or carriage return...?

Comment: @dadde: CR LF is a line terminator. If a "line" contains just CR LF then it is empty. If it contains Space CR LF then it may be described as "blank" but is not empty. What do you mean by "it did not really work"? What did it do that you did not expect it to do, or what did it not do that you expected it to do?

Comment: @Magoo It did not remove the lines containing only CRLF

Comment: @dadde: Strange. It does for me. You do realise that it creates a new file with the empty lines removed and leaves the original file alone, don't you? May be a stupid question, but I can see no other way that this simple one-line can fail.

Comment: @Magoo yes I understood that. maybe because I'm doing this in a Windows Server 2003 environment.

Comment: @dadde: Can't duplicate because I don't have access to a Winserver 2003 machine, but it shouldn't make any difference - `for /f` should ignore empty lines in all editions AFAIAA (except if used with the `/n` switch, I believe...)